# define a type $0$ grammar to accept the language

Tags: discrete-mathematics, context-free-grammar, turing-machines

I have a trouble with implementing a $0$ grammar rule to accept the language
$\{ww| w\in (0+1)^*\}$. 
I want to split the sentence by half with some specific symbol and compare each part of the sentence.
E.g. the initial sentence is 
$$101101$$
I can modify it to 
$$\text{_}101X101\text{_}$$
And now I need rules to compare these two parts.
Any tips?

Comment: You can proceed as follows: first generate paired symbols, then move them around to their final places. For the last, you’ll need a marker, so you should generate it at some step in an appropriate place too.

Comment: I solved it!no more actual. thx